# Should you use accessors on complex data types?

Tags: c++, accessor, data-protection

Should you use accessors on complex data types? Here is an example:

Say I've got a `Player` class and inside it theres a `Sprite` object. Let's say the `Sprite` object has a `setPosition()` accessor method. Now let's say I want to call that method through the player, so I create an accessor to the `Sprite` object in the `Player`.

```
class Player
{
public:
    const Sprite& getSprite() const;

private:
    Sprite sprite;
}
```

Now let's say I create a 'Player' object, how do I call `setPosition` on the `sprite`? I can't just say `playerObject.getSprite().setPosition();` because the `Sprite` reference the `getSprite()` method returns is const.

Should I just make the `sprite` object public in this situation considering the `sprite` object has protection against all it's members? Or is that a bad practice and I do need to use accessors?

Comment: you should consider the [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) principles. From the standpoint of modularization and maintainability of your code, the answer to your question might not be what you're asking for explicitly. As a start, you might want to separate game logic from presentation (sprites, etc)

Answer (score 0):

There is no good answer:

Having a 2D point:

```
class Point {
    public:
    // Skipping constructors here.
    int x() const { return m_x; }
    int x&() { return m_x; }
    int y() const { return m_y; }
    int y&() { return m_y; }

    private:
    int m_x;
    int m_y;
};
```

looks like an overkill compared to

```
struct Point {
    int x;
    int y;
};
```

The first allows you to change the internal data (lets say) to a std::vector and the second data structure allows no changes. Even the first is cumbersome, I prefer that (but it is a matter of taste)